# Unable to insert a line break with \n

Tags: javascript, regex

In the simplified example below the string "quis" is replaced by wathever the user enters in the input box.
I would like to be able to insert line breaks as well from the input box.

So if the user enters something like 
"blabla\nbla"
The result should be

"blabla

bla
"

I don't want to use HTML tags like

```js
function replace_with(e) {
  var replacement = document.getElementById('replaceWith').value;
  var text = document.getElementById('val');
  var reg = new RegExp("quis", "g");
  text.innerHTML = globalString.replace(reg,replacement);
}

document.getElementById('replaceWith').addEventListener('keyup', replace_with);

var globalString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
```

```css
#val{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.input{
    border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" class="input" id="replaceWith">
 
<div id="val" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: try this: ```str.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');```

Comment: @Saad, I forgot to mention that I dont want to use html tags. Is it possible in another way?

Comment: Instead of `<div id='val'>` you could use a "preformatted" tag, ie `<pre id='val'>`.  That should display carriage returns as expected.  But it will be ugly.

Comment: @James, Just tried but, it doesnt insert a new line. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6tLzha8c/4/)

Comment: Ah right.  It's because the two separate characters backslash + n, when typed in by a user, don't become the single "carriage return" character.  They stay as two separate characters.  You would have to do a replace similar to   `text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace("\\n", "\n");` to convert them to carriage returns.  THEN your `<pre>` should work right (but remain ugly).

Comment: @James, That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason it only replaces the first instance but the the others. Any idea? This behaviour only seems to happen when replacing \n all other characters are replaced fine

Answer (score 1):

put `<br>` in innerHTML instead of `\n` to get line break

Answer (score 1):

Escaping line breaks as \n only works inside text.
Since you replace the contents of a HTML tag, you should use one `<br>` if the text needs to go to the next line, or two times `<br><br>` to leave a blank line between the two.

Comment: Is there no alternative? I really dont want to use br tags

Comment: @MK01111000 The alternative is using a textarea for the output since that can render special characters in text. But that's a bit more annoying to style. Or the pre tag as James suggest, but that'll be even uglier.

Comment: But then you also need to use the HTML entity for a new line instead of \n, so some combination of &#013; and &#010; So that won't be a solution either if you Really need to use \n.